# Mongodb find error

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

Tengo un error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] al hacer una consulta para traer varios documentos en NextJs con la libreria de mongodb

```
let doc = await req.db.collection('orders').find({ email: 'test@test.com' })
res.json(doc)
```

si pongo findOne me funciona pero obviamente me trae solo un documento. Soy bastante novato con mongodb pero por lo que he podido averiguar la consulta en teoría me debería de devolver todos los documentos que tengan el campo de email : test@test.com

Comment: que ORM estas utilizando?

Comment: @Christian estoy usando solo la libreira de mongodb en nextjs, no se si hará falta dar alguna información más

Comment: deberías agregar los detalles importantes en la pregunta, no puedo ayudarte ya que no sé nada de nextjs y sé poco de mongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que la conexión y demás configuraciones funcionan de forma correcta.

El método `find` regresa un objeto `cursor`, para obtener todos los documentos de dicho cursor se debe usar el [método toArray()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor.toarray--):

```
let doc = await req.db.collection('orders').find({ email: 'test@test.com' }).toArray();
res.json(doc)
```

Enlaces relacionados [find mongoDB](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/#find-all-documents)

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Solucionado, que no haya encontrado esto con todo lo que busque... Gracias por la ayuda y sobre todo por tu tiempo

Comment: Es confuso, ya que cuando se usa por ejemplo `findOne`, si trae el dato directamente, uno esperaría que con `find` fuera lo mismo, pero te avienta el cursor. Además también recuerdo que me confundia con `toArray()`, pensaba que era un método de JS, pero es de la API de `mongodb`, saludos